# Search filter : minimum characters

Tags: php

Here is the simple code i use for minimum 3 characters check.
I would like to make an exception if query is fully numeric ( code also has an option to search by case IDs, which are shorter than 3 characters).

```
<?php

if (strlen($_POST['Search'])>=3) {

include 'search.php';

} else {

$message = '3+ characters, please';

}

?>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write something like this:

```
// make sure no notices are emitted if the input is not as expected
$search = isset($_POST['Search']) ? $_POST['Search'] : null;

if (!ctype_digit($search)) {
    // it's all digits
}
else if (strlen($search) < 3) {
    // error: less than three characters
}
else {
    // default case
}
```

Feel free to merge the branches is the default case and the "all digits" case should forward to the same code.

**Important**: Use **only** [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) for checking if the input is all digits. [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) will return `true` for other types of input as well:

> Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits,
>   optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6
>   is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal notation (0xFF) is allowed too
>   but only without sign, decimal and exponential part.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
if (strlen($_POST['Search'])>=3 ||is_numeric($_POST['Search'])) {
  //Do stuff
} else
//do other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly:

```
<?php

if (is_numeric($_POST['Search']) || strlen($_POST['Search'])>=3) {

?>
```